# JAVA + Scan document

Tags: java, image-scanner

I need to write a very simple application in Java to run a document scanner from a web page. I understand that this must be done with the help of TWAIN, but I do not know how. Can someone guide me towards how to do scanning in Java? An example would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You could take a look at the Morena API which we used in my company to control a scanner from a web page:

[Morena website](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html)

I think there is a tutorial on this web page.