# What libraries do I need to use a paper scanner in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, japplet, image-scanner

I need to implement scanning software in a java program I am working on, what libraries will I need to do this? I have heard of JTwain and JSANE. Do I need to pay for both of these if I wish to make my software for commercial use?

Comment: What platforms do you need to support "JTwain supports Win32 only. For Java image acquisition on Mac/Linux/HPUX/BSD/Solaris/Unix, you need JSANE" - also, for commercial use, yes, you are required to pay

Comment: ok well ideally I want it to support all platforms, so in that case would I only need to buy a single license for JSANE, since I'm the only developer?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783131/java-scan-document. You should look at the Morena API http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html

Comment: @Vivek good one!  I was racking my brain for that!

Comment: @MatthewPigram if you were looking at JSane, I would, personally, recommend the Advance Developer, it just about gives you everything that the full source site option does, but costs a lot less.  But I'd check out Morena as it's aim is to be a more centralised API!

Comment: well which of the above here would best meet my needs? All I really need to be able to do is scan in a document within my program and then perform some tasks after it has been scanned in. Ideally I would like all major platforms supported (Unix/Linux, Windows & Mac), I dont really need any particularly powerful features....

Comment: @MatthewPigram are you developing a desktop or a web application? If the latter, you can check out Dynamic Web TWAIN. The SDK supports document scanning in both Windows & Mac. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx

Comment: its a Java Web Start application, so I need to use a library/package designed for Java, the link above is for web servers only right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSANE, JTWAIN and Morena are the options. I selected Morena due to its cross platform compatibility and its ability to use both SANE and TWAIN interfaces.