# Running paper scanner software with java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet, image-scanner

I was wondering if there is any way to bring up a scanners software using java. Basically I want to be able to have a user click on a "scan in document" button and then whatever scanner is installed on the users PC will come up asking for scan options and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at this question [What libraries do I need to use a paper scanner in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732857/what-libraries-do-i-need-to-use-a-paper-scanner-in-java)

But basically, depending on the platform you're aiming for you could try

[JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/) and/or [JSane](http://asprise.com/product/jsane/)

or try [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html)

I've used Morena in the past and found it very easy to use, but I'm waiting for there WIA implementation to be completed

Comment: there is now way to run it using something like Runtime.getRuntime.exec("default scanner")?

Comment: @MatthewPigram not really, that's the whole point of the Twain and Sane API's.  If you know of a particular front end that interfaces into those API's then you could.

Comment: bummer, I was the one who posted that prior question you linked above, I was looking for an alternative to using a library like JTwain. I was hoping for something similar to how printing works

Comment: @MatthewPigram technically, *"how printing works"* is what these libraries are doing.  They're bridging a common interface between your application and the drivers.  Printing just happens to be built in

Comment: yeh, but i have to pay for these ones haha